# Creating single instance or multiple instance of service layer in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I want to know what should I use to expose my service layer for nodejs api
What are the pros and cons of using the approach 1 and 2.

```
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  // approach 1
  const test = testService.play();

  // approach 2
  const testService = new TestService();
  testService.play();
});

------ testService.js --------

class TestService {
  play() {}
}

// approach 1
module.exports = new TestService();
// approach 2
module.exports = TestService;
```

Comment: in the first approach. why do you use `await`?  do you want to know what is difference between the two `module.exports` approach?

Comment: I have updated the code snippet, Just wanted to know how should we export TestService.